# Master page for Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I use Ionic for my iOS hybrid application,
I want to create a custom header and use a background image for all pages.

I want to know is there any way to create a master page in Ionic + AngularJS for using in another pages?

Answer (score 0):

The answer varies depending on how you've already setup your app. Probably the simplest approach is to use a background image with CSS on the body of the page. That is just one line of CSS, but you'll have to consider how that image works or displays on various device sizes or if your app is in portrait or landscape mode.